# Dynamically displaying a checkbox in C++ windows Forms

Tags: c++, button, checkbox, windows-forms-designer

I would like to display a checkbox dynamically on clicking a button in C++ windows Forms. How could I achieve that. I wrote the following code in a button click event.

```
System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^  checkBox9;
checkBox9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
checkBox9->AutoSize = true;
checkBox9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(43, 38);
checkBox9->Name = L"checkBox9";
checkBox9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(98, 21);
checkBox9->TabIndex = 1;
checkBox9->Text = L"checkBox9";
checkBox9->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
checkBox9->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::checkBox9_CheckedChanged);
```

But this does not work. I am unable to display the check box on clicking the button. Please support.

Comment: Where and how are you adding this checkbox to the form? The code shown only create a checkbox, but doesn't attach it to the form

Comment: Initially I added a button and a checkbox statically in a Form and generated the above code for checkbox. Then I took a copy of the code and I removed the checkbox from the design and then I added the copied code inside the button click event. But this does not work when clicking the button.

Comment: Then you missed something while copying this code, as it is missing the part where it is adding the checkbox to a container in your form (as I already mentioned). Since it is not part of the form it obviously does not show up

Comment: Yes I have missed the Add control function call. Now I added the call and works fine.